# How to leave cell blank if cell is blank?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How will I leave my cell blank if I have this formula?

```
=if(O2<>"",roundup(O2-E2,0),"")
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(O2),,ROUNDUP(O2-E2, 0))
```